# Imprimir un símbolo en vez de un número de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una lista

```
a = [1,2,3,5,5,0,2]
```

Quiero imprimir:

> 1 2 3 -- -- 0 2

Me imagino que habrá que crear otra lista en la que sustituyo los `5` por `--` (guiones).

¿Y si quisiera imprimir espacios en vez de `--`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que lo más sencillo es crear un mapeo con los valores que quieres reemplazar, luego mediante una lista de comprensión puedes crear una nueva lista:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,5,5,0,2]
>>> reemplazos = {5: '--'}
>>> [reemplazos.get(x, x) for x in a]
[1, 2, 3, '--', '--', 0, 2]
```

Al usar `reemplazos.get(x, x)` estás usando el mismo número si es que no se encuentra su reemplazo en el diccionario.

Para imprimirlo:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,5,5,0,2]
>>> reemplazos = {5: '--'}
>>> nueva_lista = [reemplazos.get(x, x) for x in a]
>>> salida = ' '.join(str(x) for x in nueva_lista)
>>> print(salida)
1 2 3 -- -- 0 2
```

Puedes reemplazar el `--` por cualquier otra cosa (espacio, carita feliz, etc.)

Comment: me imagino que en salida "...." en vez de nueva_list es nueva_lista.
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @MiguelNavaza así es. Disculpa, fue un error al copiar de mi terminal a la pregunta :-)

Answer (score 0):

Recorre la lista y cambia todos los valores de 5 por valores vacíos que es lo que deseas imprimir o el valor que tú quieras.

for x in range(0,len(lista)):

```
If  lista[x] == 5:

          lista[x] = " "
```

Después imprimes tu lista.

for x in range(0,len(lista)):

```
print lista[x]
```

Y ya tendrás tu lista con caracteres o espacios vacíos. Saludos.

Comment: La comparación debería ser contra un entero según la pregunta: `if lista[x] == 5`.

Comment: Tiene razón. Gracias por la aclaración