# Sustituir en una lista de números un número por un símbolo y redondear a 2 decimales al resto

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una lista

```
a = [ 1 , 2.5 , 3.34 , 5 , 5 , 0 , 2.0 ]
```

Quiero imprimir

```
1.00  2.50  3.34  --  --  0.00  2.00
```

Lo he intentado así entre otras formas

```
def add_two_floats (notasalumno):
    """Añadir dos decimales a las notas si tienen menos, rellenando con ceros a la derecha"""    
    two_floats = ["%.2f"%i for i in notasalumno]
    print (two_floats)  #Esta sería solo para depurar


def reemplaza_ceros (notasalumno_two_floats):
    """Reemplazo los ceros por guiones al imprimir el boletin de alumnos"""
    for x in range(0,len(notasalumno_two_floats)):
        if notasalumno_two_floats[x] == "0.00":
            notasalumno_two_floats[x] = "----"
```

Comment: A primera vista creí haber entendido la idea, pero por qué 2.5 retornaría 2.00 y no 2.50 ? ¿Qué desea sustituir?   [¿busca algo como esto?](https://repl.it/repls/WigglyAjarRuby)

Comment: Es un error. en vez de 2.00 sería 2.50

Comment: Además quiero cambiar los números 5 (u otro número concreto, el que decida el profesor) por símbolos. Es para un boletín de notas de alumnos, en donde cierto número no debe aparecer al imprimir pero si el espacio o en este caso el símbolo guion --

Comment: @MiguelNavaza Pero eso ya lo habías preguntado [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142368/imprimir-un-s%c3%admbolo-en-vez-de-un-n%c3%bamero-de-una-lista) Sólo tienes que combinar ambas respuestas

Comment: he intentado combinar las dos y aún no lo he logrado. Por eso lo pregunto combinada. me imagino que hago dos funciones donde retorno una lista  con los decimales y a esa lista le  aplico la segunda funcion. para que retorne los --

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado para indicarte donde esta el error y que lo corrijas, si no pensaremos que quieres que hagamos tu trabajo.

Comment: La primera función debería retornar la lista que ha creado. Esa lista se la puedes pasar como parámetro a la segunda función. Ya puestos, yo cambiaría la segunda función para que, en lugar de modificar directamente la lista recibida, cree una nueva y la retorne, igual que hace la primera función.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he resuelto así. Os muestro parte del código y como queda impreso.
`alumnosClase` es una variable que almacena nombre, apellidos, notas alumno en cada evaluaciones y nota media total.

```
def cuerpo_informe_resultados():
    """Imprime el cuerpo de resultado examen alumnos"""
    for unAlumno in alumnosClase:
        n = unAlumno[0]  # Nombre del alumno
        s = unAlumno[1]  # Apellido del alumno
        neal = unAlumno[2]  # Notas alumno en cada evaluación
        nmeval = unAlumno[3]  # Notas media todas evaluaciones del alumno        
        reemplaza_ceros_floats(neal)
        add_two_floats (nmeval)
        if len(n) <= 18 and len(s) <= 15:                           
            print(n[:18].ljust(20, " "), "\t", s[0:15].ljust(15, " "), '  '.join(str(x) for x in nueva),
                  "  ", '   '.join(str(e) for e in nmal))                         
        elif len(n) >= 18 and len(s) <= 15:
            print(n[:17].ljust(20, "."), "\t", s[0:15].ljust(15, " "), '  '.join(str(x) for x in nueva),
                  "  ", '   '.join(repr(e) for e in nmal))
        elif len(n) <= 18 and len(s) >= 15:
            print(n[:18].ljust(20, " "), "\t", s[0:12].ljust(15, "."), '  '.join(str(x) for x in nueva),
                  "  ", '   '.join(repr(e) for e in nmal))
        else:
            print(n[:17].ljust(20, "."), "\t", s[0:12].ljust(15, "."), '  '.join(str(x) for x in nueva),
                  "  ", '   '.join(repr(e) for e in nmal))


def add_two_floats (notamediaeval):
    """Añadir dos decimales a las notas si tienen menos, rellenando con ceros y remplazar ceros por guiones
    al imprimir boletin de alumnos"""    
    two_floats = [format(float(i), '.2f') for i in notamediaeval]
    reemplazos = {'0.00': ' -- '}
    global nmal
    nmal = [reemplazos.get(x, x) for x in two_floats]
    return nmal


def reemplaza_ceros_floats (notasalumnos):
    """Añadir dos decimales a las notas si tienen menos, rellenando con ceros a la derecha.
    Reemplazo los ceros por guiones al imprimir el boletin de alumnos. """
    listformat = [format(float(i), '.2f') for i in notasalumnos]
    reemplazos = {'0.00': ' -- '}
    global nueva
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que la función `reemplaza_ceros_floats()` sobra, pues no llega a hacer su cometido, ni retorna ningún resultado. Tendrías que quitar también la línea que llama a esa función. Por otro lado, no debes usar variables globales para almacenar los resultados de una función. Elimina la declaración `global nmal` de la función `add_two_floats()`, y en el lugar donde la llamas recoge su resultado a una variable global, mediante `nmal = add_two_floats(nmeval)`. En general, intenta eliminar todas las variables globales del programa

Comment: Al generar notas (mediante otra función que no aparece en el código que publiqué aquí), a veces me crea notas con un solo decimal con lo que me descuadra el boletín. Voy a revisar lo que me comentas. Muchas.